# I cant use a string in myRef.push().setValue()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to upload an email to a Firebase Database but when i create the account it doesnt creates the **email** in the database, but yes in the Firebase Authentication

```
private void registrarUsuario(){

                final String email2 = TextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password2 = pass.getText().toString().trim();
    //...

    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
          if (task.isSuccessful()) { 
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Se ha registrado el usuario con el email: " + TextEmail.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("people");

    myRef.push().setValue(email2);
```

Comment: What's your database structure?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. and check if getting any exception. 
and do add read write true in database rules.

```
ref.push.setValue(email, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
        if (firebaseError != null) {
            System.out.println("Data could not be saved. " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Data saved successfully.");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It's working now, the error was that the database didn't have time to check if the data was correct.  Solved adding a Handler

Comment: then add index database rules

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what these symbols `**` mean in your code `myRef.push().setValue(email2**);`
but maybe be this is the reason for your problem.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Sorry, it's a typing error, but it's working now!! Thanks you for answer!